# ganache-cli issues: - How to retrive old ganache-cli account once cmd window close

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, private-blockchain, ethereum-wallet-dapp

I am using `ganache-cli`....and it is providing me 10 test accounts with 100ETH balance.

when I close that cmd and start ganache-cli it creates new 10 test accounts every time.

So how to retrieve my old account bcoz i have used that account reference in whole application?

Answer (score 3):

you can try to execute it with the `deterministic` flag

```
ganache-cli --deterministic
```

this will try to generate the same addresses anytime if possible. You can add another parameter, `db`, to save also the chain database (with all the transactions) so you can load it again in the next executions

```
ganache-cli --deterministic --db [path]
```

if the db exists it will be loaded and you should have the historical data of the previous transactions.

Answer (score 1):

To make it work with the deterministic option, you have to supply the same mnemonic each time you start.

`ganache-cli -d -m 'brass bus same payment express already energy direct type have venture afraid'`

**-d** == **--deterministic**

**-m** == **--mnemonic**